# Update List Item SPfx not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx, spfx-webparts, sphttpclient

Below is the code, which is not working, shows below error

> An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.

```
 const body: string = {
                    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.InputsListItem' }, 'IsMapped': true
                };
    this.props.spHttpClient.post(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items(${item.Id})`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
          'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'odata-version': '',
          'IF-MATCH': '*',
          'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      });
  })
  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): void => {
    this.setState({
      status: `Item with ID: ${latestItemId} successfully updated`,
      items: []
    });
  }, (error: any): void => {
    this.setState({
      status: `Error updating item: ${error}`,
      items: []
    });
```

Comment: Be more specific. What does not work exactly? What is the error? What value is under listItemEntityTypeName?

Comment: The listitem metadata might be the problem,

 var item = {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.Data.listnameListItem" // change the listname
        },
        "columnname": "value"
    };

Comment: Check if you are using the correct internal column name

Comment: Even when I tried to update any other column, its same error, moreover generic error says "Bad Request"

Answer (score 1):

My test code for your reference.

```
let body: string = JSON.stringify({
      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.InputsListItem' }, 'IsMapped': true
  });
  body = body.substring(1, body .length-1);
  body = '{' + body +'}';
  this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Inputs')/items(1)`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
      'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
      'odata-version': '',
      'IF-MATCH': '*',
      'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE'
      },
      body: body
      })
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): void => {
        console.log(response);
      }, (error: any): void => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without Rest with sp-pnp-js package:

```
import sp from "sp-pnp-js";

sp.web.lists.getByTitle(this.props.listName)
            .items.getById(item.Id).update({ IsMapped: true })
```